# How would you throttle a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

Let's suppose I want to run a recursive function that will take weeks, months or even years to complete. It returns all possible permutations of a string based on the specified parameters. While it's running, I want to be able to see how far along it is progressing - e.g. how many permutations it has generated so far. In a nutshell, I want a very long-running recursive function to execute without locking up my UI.

Also, I would like to do this with vanilla ES5, **not** in strict mode, and without WebWorkers. It should be able to run in IE9.

What I have works fine as-is, but when I raise `numspaces` to 10, for example, the browser locks up. So I am *assuming* that I am just working the browser too hard, and "throttling" the amount of work it has to do would help solve this problem. I did try increasing the `setTimeout` delays from 1 to 250 and even 1000, but the browser still locked up.

I am interested in this simply because I tried to do it, and couldn't. Also, I know for a fact that this code is terribly inefficient and there are much, much better ways to do what I am looking to achieve. So recommend them!

```js
var inputString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function allPossibleCombinations(input, length, curstr, callback) {
  if (curstr.length === length) return callback(curstr);
  
  (function(n) {
    setTimeout(allPossibleCombinations.bind(n, input, length, curstr + input[n], callback), 1);

    n++;
    
    if (n < input.length) setTimeout(arguments.callee.bind(n,n), 1);
  })(0);
}

var totalResults = 0,
    numDigits = inputString.length,
    numSpaces = 2,
    maxResults = Math.pow(numDigits, numSpaces),
    consoleElement = document.getElementById('console'),
    startTime = +new Date();

console.log("Starting.. expecting", maxResults, "total results...");

allPossibleCombinations(inputString.split(""), numSpaces, "", function(result) {
  totalResults++;

  if (totalResults === maxResults) {
    var elapsed = +new Date() - startTime;
    
    consoleElement.innerText = "Done.";
    console.log("Completed in", elapsed, "ms!");
  } else {
    // Do something with this permutation...
    //...
    
    // Show progress...
    var progress = ((totalResults / maxResults) * 100).toFixed(2) * 1;
    consoleElement.innerText = progress + "%";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re getting close with the `setTimeout`, but the current implementation queues up all the timers for a given prefix at once, resulting in an exponential number of timers and quick memory exhaustion. One small change would be to create another callback to indicate completion and use it to wait on recursive calls, never holding more than one timer at once:

```js
var inputString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function allPossibleCombinations(input, length, curstr, resultCallback, doneCallback) {
  if (curstr.length === length) {
    resultCallback(curstr);
    doneCallback();
    return;
  }
  
  var n = 0;
  
  (function next() {
    if (n === input.length) {
      doneCallback();
      return;
    }
  
    allPossibleCombinations(
      input, length, curstr + input[n],
      resultCallback,
      function () {
        n++;
        setTimeout(next, 0);
      });
  })();
}

var totalResults = 0,
    numDigits = inputString.length,
    numSpaces = 4,
    maxResults = Math.pow(numDigits, numSpaces),
    consoleElement = document.getElementById('console'),
    startTime = +new Date();

console.log("Starting.. expecting", maxResults, "total results...");

allPossibleCombinations(
  inputString.split(""), numSpaces, "",
  function (result) {
    totalResults++;

    // Do something with this permutation...
    //...

    // Show progress...
    var progress = ((totalResults / maxResults) * 100).toFixed(2) * 1;
    consoleElement.innerText = progress + "%";
  },
  function () {
    var elapsed = +new Date() - startTime;

    consoleElement.innerText = "Done.";
    console.log("Completed in", elapsed, "ms!");
  });
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

That’s really slow, though. Thinking of how you could write this as a generator:

```
function* strings(input, length, current) {
    if (current.length === length) {
        yield current;
        return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        yield* strings(input, length, current + input[i]);
    }
}
```

and translating that to a system where the callback is responsible for resuming generation:

```
function strings(input, length, current, yield_, continue_) {
    if (current.length === length) {
        yield_(current, continue_);
        return;
    }

    var i = 0;

    (function next() {
        if (i === input.length) {
            continue_();
            return;
        }

        strings(input, length, current + input[i++], yield_, next);
    })();
}
```

you can have the flexibility of setting a timer as infrequently as you’d like for performance.

```js
"use strict";

function countSequences(n, k) {
    var result = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        result *= n--;
    }

    return result;
}

function strings(input, length, current, yield_, continue_) {
    if (current.length === length) {
        yield_(current, continue_);
        return;
    }

    var i = 0;

    (function next() {
        if (i === input.length) {
            continue_();
            return;
        }

        var c = input[i++];
        strings(input.replace(c, ''), length, current + c, yield_, next);
    })();
}

var inputString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var totalResults = 0;
var numDigits = inputString.length;
var numSpaces = 5;
var maxResults = countSequences(numDigits, numSpaces);
var consoleElement = document.getElementById('console');
var startTime = +new Date();

console.log("Starting… expecting", maxResults, "total results.");

strings(
    inputString, numSpaces, "",
    function (result, continue_) {
        if (totalResults++ % 1000 === 0) {
            var progress = (totalResults / maxResults * 100).toFixed(2);
            consoleElement.innerText = progress + "% (" + result + ")";
            setTimeout(continue_, 0);
        } else {
            continue_();
        }
    },
    function () {
        var elapsed = +new Date() - startTime;

        consoleElement.innerText = "Done.";
        console.log("Completed in", elapsed, "ms!");
    });
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

(This style is still non-optimal, but it’ll never finish for 26<sup>10</sup> no matter how quick individual operations are.)

Comment: Excellent answer. This does a great job of explaining why my code is inefficient, and also provides alternatives with explanations about how they work. Exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Comment: How would I best modify this solution to now calculate only unique combinations of the input string? E.g. input string "ab", output "ab", "ba" (rather than "aa", "bb", "ab", "ba")

Comment: @bosscube: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order is an in-place algorithm, but if you want to yield a copy of the result anyway then you can just as well create a copy of the alphabet with the current value removed (`var current = input[i++];` and pass `input.replace(current, '')` as `input` to the recursive call) – it’s the same time complexity. Let me know if you’d like a code sample for either.

Comment: Hmm I'm still having trouble - could you modify the 2nd snippet you posted? This is extremely helpful to me, thank you!

Comment: @bosscube: Modified. It’s pretty much just removing what’s been used from the alphabet available to later characters.

Comment: Got it; this is great! Thank you very much for taking the time to explain it. I've learned a lot from this!